# Move an element from div to anther - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, move

I am trying to MOVE Grid3 to Grid2 - and I am using This code, but it's not working, what I am doing wrong?

Also is there anyway to move half of the Div's in Grid3 to Grid1, and the other half to Grid2?

**JS**

```
$("#grid3").appendTo("#grid2");
```

**HTML**

```
        <div class="wrapperA1">
            <div class="content">
                <div id="home-sectionD">
                    <div id="grid1"><!--Gird 1-->   

                        <article class="testimonial">
                        <img alt="Neal Kilburne​​" src="assets/images/neal kilburne​​.jpg"/>
                            <div>
                                <h3>Neal Kilburne​​</h3>
                                <p>CEO, iTEQ Global www.iteqglobal.com</p>
                                    <br>
                                <p>“Loai is a great asset to our company and provides us with great and quick responses,Such a talented designer which we have the honour of working with.” 2011 - 2012</p>
                            </div>  
                        </article>

                        <article class="testimonial">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Amanda Chui​</h3>
                                <p>Owner of www.beautyroom.ca</p>
                                    <br>
                                <p>Just what my website needed! When I had finished my website, I felt that it was missing something,so I enlisted in the help of Loai. He did a great job of giving my website the professional and polished look it needed without having me wait for days on end. Thanks, Loai!” June 23, 2012</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                    </div><div id="grid2"><!--Gird 2-->     

                        <article class="testimonial">
                            <img alt="Geeta Martinez" src="assets/images/geeta martinez.jpg"/>
                            <div>
                                <h3>Geeta Martinez</h3>
                                <p>Lawyer &amp; Business Consultant</p>
                                    <br>
                                <p>"Leo did a great job! He designed and put together several websites for me in less than a week. He was incredibly patient and flexible throughout the whole process, and took a lot of the stress out of the whole situation for me. He is a really nice guy to work with - I really appreciated his approach! I would definitely recommend working with him". July 14, 2013</p>
                            </div>  
                        </article>

                        <article class="testimonial">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Richard Jackson</h3>
                                <p><em>Photographer www.rjpstudios.co.uk​</em></p>
                                    <br>
                                <p>“Loai designed my website last year on wix though I could have done it myself loai added a proffesional touch to the design which is so important in creating the best first impeson.” 2013</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>  

                    </div><div id="grid3"><!--Gird 3-->         

                        <article class="testimonial">
                            <img alt="Glen Eric Huysamer" src="assets/images/glen eric huysamer.jpg"/>
                            <div>
                                <h3>Glen Eric Huysamer​</h3>
                                <p>Specialist Service Provider.</p>
                                    <br>
                                <p>“I would like to take this opportunity to warn people who might consider using Loai Design Studio. You will have to buckle up and strap yourself in as this young designer and associates take you through the process of creating your design needs. I was pleasantly surprised from start to finish, and can say that even though Loai took control of the creative process the end result felt like it was mine. You can not go wrong with this young lad, go ahead surprise yourself”. December 30, 2011</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                        <article class="testimonial">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Ciprian Filip​</h3>
                                <p>Founder of Pontomat.ro​</p>
                                    <br>
                                <p>“Worked with Loai on designing exposure of our social media presence on Facebook for our E-commerce initiative. He is very passionate and expert in his field of work, coming with breakthrough innovations in real time. He is able to manage an end to end social media exposure with accent on clarity, effectiveness and innovation. His working capabilities are awesome and I am sure that he will make good contribution to any project he works on.”  August 4, 2011</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the jQuery code from? Before the HTML? Is it wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });`? Is it on some sort of event?

Comment: Not enough information here to provide an answer. Is that append being triggered by an event?  Are you sure that event is being fired properly?

Comment: Fixed the problem, sorry for the lake of information, I am trying to make it append it when the screen size is under 770px... I am using the following code and it's not working as well!
`$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));
     function listenWidth() {
  if($(window).width()<770)
 $('#grid3').find('article').appendTo('#grid2');
 };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working for me (http://jsfiddle.net/k2NMD/9/).

You may be calling append too early, before the browser has actually processed all of the html. Try wrap your append function in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid3").appendTo("#grid2");
});
```

Comment: This worked, the problem seems like it trigger the function when the content isn't ready yet.

Is there a way to append half of the Div's inside the Grid3 to Grid1 & Grid2?

Comment: Of course. Check out [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/k2NMD/14/). This is assuming that half of your content is inside <article class="testimonial"></article>. If it's not, you'll have to wrap half of your content in a div and give it a different class. Then replace "testimonial" with the new class name in the javascript code.

Comment: This worked, however if lets say I have 4 articles inside Grid3, only the first two will be moved to Grid1 and Grid2, and the rest 2 articles will stay under Grid3, no way around it with Java rather having each half inside a div? Thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36045/discussion-between-leo-and-fuzzley)

Answer (score 0):

The move does work (if you are running the code after the document has loaded such as in `$(document).ready()` event). Check in the developer console for the elements (if you are using Chrome) to see that `#grid3` is actually inside `#grid2` like so

```
<div id="grid2">...
    <article...>
    <article...>
    <div id="grid3">...
</div>
```

If you would like to move the contents of `grid3` inside `grid2`, then you have to get the articles using `$('#grid3').find('article').appendTo('#grid2')` and that will remove the articles from `grid3` and insert it into `grid2`. Moving parts of it can be accomplished by separating the `article` and insert one into `grid1` and the other into `grid2`.